# PHP: get xml children without parent

Tags: php, xml

I load `XML` file by `simplexml_load_file`

> XML :

```
<list>
   <top>
      <test>
         <id>1</id>
      </test>
      <test>
         <id>2</id>
      </test>
      <test>
         <id>3</id>
      </test>
   </top>
   <test>
       <id>4</id>
   </test>
</list>
```

I want get all `TEST` tag by **one** `foreach`

I dont use `top` parent for get `test` chilren

How i can ?

Comment: The php docs http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php have an example of what you want to do

Comment: This example used 3 foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all `TEST` elements which are anywhere in XML? In that case you can use xpath somelike this

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('xml.xml'); 
$testElements = $xml->xpath('//*/test'); // return array of TEST elements
```